# How to group by and select

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to extract customer who has type `a`

I guess I must group by in `customer` and tried to having in `type`

```
customer type
A         a  
A         c
B         b 
B         c
C         a
C         a
```

but I couldn't figure out specific way to achieve this.
If someone has opinion,please let me know.

My desired result is following

```
customer type
A        a
A        c
C        a
C        a
```

Thanks

Comment: So your desired result is any row that has either 'A' or 'a' on both customer and type column?
If so then just:
SELECT customer, type
FROM tablename
WHERE customer = 'A' OR type = 'a'

Comment: You want to select from the table *where* a certain condition is met (`WHERE` clause). The condition is that there *exists* a row with a certain type for the customer in the table (`EXISTS` clause). There are other solutions, but this is the straight-forward way.

Comment: Please add the rules (aka conditions) you want to apply here. Otherwise you'll get wild guessing and guessed results.

Comment: Just to get this straight: Using an `IN` cause is as much straight-forward as an `EXISTS`clause of course (and I even like it better for its simplicity). The wording sounds a little more complicated, while the query is actually shorter than the query with an exists clause: The condition is that the customer is 'in* the set of customers with the desired type (`IN` clause).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using exists, we can try:

```
SELECT t1.customer, t1.type
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.customer = t1.customer AND t2.type = 'a');
```

The exists logic reads in plain English as select any record for which we can find at least one record for the same customer whose type is `a`.  This means retain all customer records, where at least one of those records has type `a`.

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to understand in subquery `WHERE t2.customer = t1.customer AND t2.type = 'a'`  why this work well .. it seems 'customer ='A' and type='c' ' will be droped..

Comment: Please check the updated answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to group. You can just filter the table for customers that have type 'a' and use that resultset to filter the table again for the customers.

```
WITH
    cust_data
    AS
        (SELECT 'A' AS customer, 'a' AS TYPE FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'A' AS customer, 'c' AS TYPE FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'B' AS customer, 'b' AS TYPE FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'B' AS customer, 'c' AS TYPE FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'C' AS customer, 'a' AS TYPE FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'C' AS customer, 'a' AS TYPE FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
FROM cust_data c
WHERE customer IN (SELECT customer
                   FROM cust_data
                   WHERE TYPE = 'a');
```

This gives

```
CUSTOMER    TYPE
A           c
A           a
C           a
C           a
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope the below query completes your requirement.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    test.customer
WHERE
    customer IN (SELECT 
            customer
        FROM
            test.customer
        WHERE
            type = 'a');
```

Output:

```
A   a
A   c
C   a
C   a
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use accessing table twice. Use window functions instead.

```
with t(customer, type) as (
select 'A', 'a' from dual union all
select 'A', 'c' from dual union all
select 'B', 'b' from dual union all 
select 'B', 'c' from dual union all
select 'C', 'a' from dual union all
select 'C', 'a' from dual)
select customer, type
from 
   (select t.*, count(decode(type, 'a', 1)) over (partition by customer) cnt
    from t
   )
where cnt > 0;

CUSTOMER TYPE
-------- ----
A        a
A        c
C        a
C        a
```